# How to set notification on ubuntu18.04 by "notify-send" and "crontab"?

Tags: ubuntu

The following is my settings by `crontab -e`, but it doesn't work.

```
*/20 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0;/usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" "Pay attention to your Eyes and Neck!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic steps that you can use in order to **troubleshoot crontab**:

1. Make your crontabs run more frequent (once every minute):

`* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" "Pay Attention to your Eyes and Neck!"`

That one works on my ubuntu 18.

2. Check your cron log

You can do that with the following commands:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

or

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: I modified my configuration according to your answer, but there is still no bubble popup.Through the log I know that notify-send has run, but But there is no reminder message in my graphical window.

Comment: The following is my log:Jul  9 22:24:01 kernellmd-X550LC CRON[6085]: (kernellmd) CMD (export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" "Pay Attention to your Eyes and Neck!")
Jul  9 22:25:01 kernellmd-X550LC CRON[6228]: (kernellmd) CMD (export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" "Pay Attention to your Eyes and Neck!")
Jul  9 22:26:01 kernellmd-X550LC CRON[6278]: (kernellmd) CMD (export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" "Pay Attention to your Eyes and Neck!")

Comment: Please make sure that your display is :0.0; `echo $DISPLAY`,
and also `whereis notify-send`. Just to make sure.

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying.I have configured as follows,but it doesn't work:  */20 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0;/usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" "Pay attention to your Eyes and Neck!"。

Answer (score 0):

try your system settings, in notification part:
enable 'notification popups'
I had same problem and solved it in this way

***update:
check whether u have notify-osd package installed(sudo apt install notify-osd)

Comment: I always enable "notification popups" in settings, but it still cant work. how do you set and where?

Comment: check whether u have notify-send package installed(sudo apt install notify-osd)

Comment: i have notify-send package and i can use "notify-send" command to send popups message successfully,but when i want to send popups message by crontab, i fail.

Comment: this is what i have write by command "crontab -e" 
    `* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/notify-send "Take A Rest Please!" 
    "Pay Attention to your Eyes and Neck!"`